script to save emails from a folder within outlook as pdf
I want to save emails from a folder created inside my outlook as pdfs into appropriate folders with their names being named according to the email sender. So whenever i run the script, it checks for the already processed emails and avoids and goes for the new one and checks whether they are from a new sender or not, if it is new sender, it creates new folder and puts the email as pdf in it or else does the same in an existing folder
Code
import os
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime
import re

# Path to the log file
log_file_path = r"processed_emails.log"

# Load the processed email IDs from the log file
if os.path.exists(log_file_path):
    with open(log_file_path, "r") as log_file:
        processed_ids = set(log_file.read().splitlines())
else:
    processed_ids = set()

# Initialize Outlook application
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Function to find the folder by name
def find_folder(folder, target_folder_name):
    if folder.Name == target_folder_name:
        return folder
    for subfolder in folder.Folders:
        result = find_folder(subfolder, target_folder_name)
        if result:
            return result
    return None

# Sanitize file name 
def sanitize_file_name(name):
    return re.sub(r'[<>:"/\\|?*]', '_', name)

# Get the root folder 
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)  # Adjust as necessary

#Outlook folder name
target_folder_name = 'testFolder'
folder = find_folder(root_folder, target_folder_name)

if not folder:
    print(f"Folder '{target_folder_name}' not found.")
else:
    # Ensure the output directory exists
    output_dir = "email_as_pdfs"
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Loop through each email in the folder
    for item in folder.Items:
        if item.Class == 43:  # 43 is the class number for MailItem
            email_id = item.EntryID

            # Process only if the email ID is not in the processed list
            if email_id not in processed_ids:
                sender_name = sanitize_file_name(item.SenderName.replace(" ", "_"))
                
                # Generate a unique name based on received date
                received_date = item.ReceivedTime.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
                email_subject = f"email_{received_date}"

                # Create a directory for the sender if it doesn't exist
                sender_dir = os.path.join(output_dir, sender_name)
                os.makedirs(sender_dir, exist_ok=True)

                # Define the path for the PDF file
                pdf_path = os.path.join(sender_dir, f"{email_subject}.pdf")
                print(f"Saving PDF to {pdf_path}")  # Debug print

                # Check if the path length is within the Windows limit
                if len(pdf_path) > 260:
                    print(f"Error: File path too long: {pdf_path}")
                    continue

                # Save the email as a PDF using Outlook's SaveAs method
                try:
                    item.SaveAs(pdf_path, 17)  # 17 is the value for olPDF
                    print(f"PDF saved successfully at {pdf_path}")

                    # Add the email ID to the processed list
                    processed_ids.add(email_id)
                    with open(log_file_path, "a") as log_file:
                        log_file.write(f"{email_id}\n")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error while saving PDF for email received at '{received_date}': {e}")

    print("Emails have been saved as PDFs.")

this is my code when i run this im getting this error
"Error while saving PDF for email received at '20240605_165544': (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, None)".
I thought this error was being thrown at me because pdf naming contained illegal characters, so i defined to function to solve that "sanitize_file_name" the same error again then i thought it was due to the path name of the pdf saving location is too long so i set a condition for it as well but still same error.

Please [edit] the question to include the complete error traceback.
